# Is there another way to create graphDb node in Neo4j in Java API?

Tags: neo4j, nodes, graph-databases, java

Let's say, i want to create 100 Nodes and import it to graphDb of neo4j, does it mean i have to call

```
Node nodeName = graphDb.createNode();
```

100 times and use 100 different names as well ? That is a lot of work.
Is there another way to create large amount of Nodes, without writing it one by one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple solutions :

A. Standard Java and simple names

```
IntStream.range(0, 1000).forEach(i -> {
    database.createNode(Label.label("Person")).setProperty("name", "person-" + i);
        });
```

B. Use java faker for generating firstnames :

https://github.com/DiUS/java-faker

C. Use graphgen online and import into your neo4j

[image]

http://graphgen.graphaware.com

D. Use the graphgen procedure for neo4j 3.x

https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-graphgen-procedure